# I have two while loops next to each other, but how do I run the second while loop with the original input when the first while loop changed the input?

Tags: c, input, while-loop, printf

Sorry for this weird question but I'm only a beginner. I created a program with two while loops next to each other. The first while loop takes user input and repeats until input=0. When the second while loop begins, it takes the input = 0 from the first while loop. How to run the second while loop with original user input? Thank you.

```
unsigned long long int inp,inp1,rem,rem1,ans=0,ans1=0,place_value=1,place_value1=1;
            
        printf("Please input binary for conversion:\n");
        scanf("%llu", &input);
        
        inp=input;
            while (input>0){
                rem=input%10; 
                ans=ans+rem*place_value;  
                input=input/10;
                place_value=place_value*2; 
            }
            while (input!=0){
                rem1 = inp1 % 10;
                ans1 = ans1 + rem * place_value1;
                place_value1 = place_value1* 2;
                inp1 = inp1 / 10;
            }

        printf("%d in Binary is %llu in Decimal Form.\n\n", inp,ans);
        printf("%d in Binary is %d in Octal Form.\n", inp1,ans1);
        printf("");
```

Comment: just save it in another variable.

Comment: I tried declaring input1 as a new variable and setting input1=input, but it didn't work. Since input is already 0 from the first loop, input1=input is essentially input1=0 (it's either this or i'm not thinking about this right).

Comment: you asked how to run the second while loop with the exact same input as the first, since the first changes the input (which is bad style, imo).
Now you say that "input1 = input" is not sufficient. what do you want?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a fix without functions. Thank you to everyone for helping me. Declaring another variable was indeed the fix, I just needed to refine it a bit more.

```
        else if(op=='B' || op=='b'){
        unsigned long long int inp,rem=0,ans=0,place_value=1;

        printf("You have chosen Binary to Decimal and Octal\n");
        printf("Please input binary for conversion:\n");
        scanf("%llu", &input);

        inp=input;
            while (input>0){
                rem=input%10; 
                ans=ans+rem*place_value;  
                input=input/10;
                place_value=place_value*2; 
            }
        unsigned long long int rem1=0,ans1=0,place_value1=1;
        input1=inp;
            while (input1!=0){
                rem1 = input1 % 10;
                ans1 = ans1 + rem1 * place_value1;
                place_value1 = place_value1 * 2;
                input1 = input1 / 10;
            }
            
        printf("%llu in Binary is %llu in Decimal Form.\n\n", inp,ans);
        printf("%llu in Binary is %o in Octal Form.\n", inp,ans1);

        main();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to define a new variable to store the input value.
`unsigned long long int value = input`

But I think this problem would be easier to resolve/read with recursion.
[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decimal-binary-number-using-recursion/) you have a working example.

Comment: I am limited to a number of concepts so I am unable to use recursion. So the solution would be to declare a new variable that is equal to the original user input? (i.e. unsigned long long int input,input1;)? And then I would state that input1=input?

Comment: Don't use recursion when it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have way too many variables in your code. And similar names which only differ by some appended number is a mess. And you are mixing it all up. For instance you never assign a value to `inp1` and you use `input` where it should have been `inp1`. You use `rem` where it should be `rem1`. It's too complicated... It's time to use functions...

```
unsigned long long int foo(unsigned long long int input)
{
    unsigned long long int rem;
    unsigned long long int ans=0;
    unsigned long long int place_value=1;

    while (input>0){
       rem = input % 10; 
       ans = ans + rem * place_value;  
       input = input / 10;
       place_value = place_value * 2; 
    }

    return ans;
}

unsigned long long int bar(unsigned long long int input)
{
    unsigned long long int rem;
    unsigned long long int ans=0;
    unsigned long long int place_value=1;

    while (input!=0){
        rem = input % 10;
        ans = ans + rem * place_value;
        place_value = place_value * 2;
        input = input / 10;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

and then use the functions like

```
unsigned long long int input, ans_foo, ans_bar; 
        
printf("Please input binary for conversion:\n");
scanf("%llu", &input);
    
ans_foo = foo(input);
ans_bar = bar(input);

printf("%d in Binary is %llu in Decimal Form.\n\n", input, ans_foo);
printf("%d in Binary is %d in Octal Form.\n", input, ans_bar);
printf("");
```

**Note** To me it seems that your two `while` loops are doing the same... but that's an unrelated mistake.

Comment: To give context, the program will ask for a binary value and return both its decimal and octal value (hence, two while loops). My initial program was butter-smooth and utilized functions. However, I found out only today that we were not allowed to use functions, and we were limited to loops. So in my original code, I removed all functions and put the two while loops together to give me a decimal and octal value respectively. Is there a possible way to find both decimal and octal values given the binary, using two while loops next to each other? Also, what would be the best way to declare --

Comment: the variables for the second loop, which uses almost the same kind of variables as the first while loop? Sorry for asking so many questions because I am new to coding.